# The distance to a line from a point, find the constant values?

Tags: geometry

I have 3 points, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)
[image]

I should find the AH height. For this i must use:
[image]

How can i find each "a", "b" and "c" values?

Comment: This is a general math question, and doesn't belong here.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line.html see here for your _a_, _b_, _c_ coefficients.. Derive them manually from equation _(4)_.

Comment: @Marton, i don't want an answer on "paper" (yes it's easy), i want the answer on "code" and it's not the same. (equation on paper or code)

Comment: @Kumul If it's easy on paper, then writing the code should be easy as well. Where are you stuck?

Comment: i mean that: I was hoping there will be a "deterministic solution" but was not. For example, how we can write a equation that we knows 2 points and angle of equation? we can't output the answer like equation. But we write the values of equation piecemeal.
My english is poor i can't explain myself correctly. (sorry for if i talking to a rough)

Comment: @Kumul Can you frame this as a question about games to avoid having your question closed? There's obvious game applications, just need to pick one.

Comment: @michael.bartnett 
my english is poor, i didn't understand your comment exactly

Comment: @Kumul At this website, we try very hard to make sure the questions asked are always relevant to games. Your question might be interpreted as relevant to games, but right now it is just about math. Are you asking this question for help with making a game?

Comment: @michael.bartnett yes, i asked this question for a game. stackexchange.com is very huge website for hierarchy. Is that what you want to say, should i asked the question in math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Kumul The way you asked it, yes. But I think it fits here. Since you're asking for a game, you can add details about the situation in the game. Then you're more likely to get answers that solve the problem in other ways besides the formula you posted. If you are just saying, "I need these coefficients for this formula," it's all about Math without any GameDev. Looks like people are taking off their close votes, so it's not a big deal, but keep in mind it's okay and preferred to add more non-math detail to questions you ask here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a, b, c` describe the line passing through `B-C` so `a = y2-y3`, `b = x2-x3` and `c = x2*y3 - x3*y2`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way to find point H (which makes finding AH trivial):

```
V1 = A - B
V2 = C - B
t = dot(V1,V2) / dot(V2,V2)
H = B + t*V2
```

Notes:

- Definition of dot product: dot(a,b) = a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y
- Another definition of dot product: dot(a,b) = |a|*|b| * cos(theta), where theta = angle between a and b.  This means you can get a free cosine out of a couple of multiplications and an addition if you play your cards right - or if we know theta==0 then we get an easy |a|*|b|.
- Picture AB and CB as two line segments that meet at B.  V1 and V2 are the line segments relative to B (as if B were 0,0).
- Points along the line BC can be defined by BC(t) = B + t*(C-B), where for example BC(0) is B, BC(1) is C, and BC(0.5) is in the middle.
- If V2 was parallel to the the x axis we could get H (the projection of V1 on V2) with a simple V1 * cos(theta).  But it's not so we have to do this: |V1|*cos(theta) * directionOf(V2), where directionOf(V2) = V2/|V2|.  We can add in an extra |V2|/|V2| to get (|V1|*|V2|*cos(theta) * V2) / (|V2|*|V2|), which is equivalent to (dot(V1,V2) / dot(V2,V2)) * V2.  Leaving out the last V2 at first gives us 't'.
- Solution taken from "Essential Mathematics for Games and Interactive Applications" by Verth & Bishop.

Comment: +1 Almost posted this exact same answer, read from the exact same book.